# Java get acces to age field

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have abstract class A, inherits class B from A, and inherits class C from B

Class A has two instance variables string **firstName**, and string **lastName** ... An accessor and a mutator method for both instance variables

Class B does not have instance variables.

Class C has one instance variable int **age**. ... An accessor and a mutator method for this instance variable

how I can access to age of an object?

I do this for both first and last name

```
personList.get(i).getLastName()
```

but when I do

```
personList.get(i).getEmail()
```

it give me an error

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] and the actual error?

Comment: You've asked this question already and you've got an answer for it. You need to check if `personList.get(i)` is an instance of the `C` class and cast it to that class before you can access the fields that only that class has.

Comment: This another question. I

Answer (score 1):

Try an approach like below:

```
foreach(A p : personList){
    if(p.getClass.equals(C.class)){
          p.getEmail();
    }
}
```